# Direct download link to OneDrive file?

Tags: node.js, url, download, ms-word, onedrive

A OneDrive sharable link looks like this: https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqmFiI7maXrRgT7PGcK_7JyZlBco. How do I get the direct download link version of this? I know with a onedrive.live/redir?<...> link I can just replace the 'redir' with 'download', but how do I do that for a link that looks like the one above? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you follow the instruction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#encoding-sharing-urls) you can generate a URL that will act on the shared item, including being able to get its content.

In your case the URL would look like https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3cvcyFBcW1GaUk3bWFYclJnVDdQR2NLXzdKeVpsQmNv/root/content

Comment: I'm sorry, how did you get that link exactly? The link uses a sharingUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1231244193912!12&authKey=1201919!12921!1". This is different than the link I have of  https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqmFiI7maXrRgT7PGcK_7JyZlBco

Comment: the `u!asfdjlasdkfjsa` segment of the URL above is actually a Base64 encoded version of your URL. Take a look at the instructions I referenced and it should explain the process.

Comment: http://rextester.com/QNSY6325 this will help to build such url (according https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/shares/shares.md)

Comment: Unfortunately, the provided instruction page no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that our @Eric, I've updated the link. It calls out the Microsoft Graph endpoint but the same pattern works for `api.onedrive.com` with minor tweaks (hostname etc)

Answer (score 11):

You can also add a simple function to your .bashrc that will do the same trick:

```
onelink() { echo -n "$1"|base64|sed "s/=$//;s/\//\_/g;s/\+/\-/g;s/^/https:\/\/api\.onedrive\.com\/v1\.0\/shares\/u\!/;s/$/\/root\/content/"; }
```

Result is the same:

```
$ onelink 'https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqmFiI7maXrRgT7PGcK_7JyZlBco'
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3cvcyFBcW1GaUk3bWFYclJnVDdQR2NLXzdKeVpsQmNv/root/content
```

Comment: Works as expected when pasted to a Git Bash on Win 10.

Comment: I had to make a minor change in my shell. I’m on Apline Linux and installed bash shell. The regular expression was broken with the error ‘ sed: bad regex '\+': Repetition not preceded by valid expression’ until I added the -r switch to sed. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work with `https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AOaPhONxGCKIlrg&cid=910FC0C1DD8E9B39&id=910FC0C1DD8E9B39%21163&parId=910FC0C1DD8E9B39%21104&o=OneUp`.

Comment: @HappyFace Your link provides already direct link to the file: https://m7bcfg.db.files.1drv.com/y4mTguy9KYeKVM8zeNZOJZgfW7-NJ5kiiLwqEmV9X8MALN1fC4XeVOa0YJKiKR7Di_Z_aoUap3SmvhC4mjdhI8WNsZc_TOF5HGJ4v2Um2I7RvYKHDUlM1kLyG2M6AgnuTRnKGiqDvuIcRLVQ5RiAGbI0SNr3mriWKXFbE8jA4JVQL2f1AnPTlfDNs6USNlu5tF4twQmvEvuntitakYrGhGUHw?