# Create a permanent public download link to OneDrive file using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to get a permanent public download link to OneDrive file using Microsoft Graph API. The goal is to have `<img src="DOWNLOAD_LINK">` on my website and the OneDrive image file works for any user who views the page.

Currently I have tried the following things:

1. `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/root:/PATH/TO/FILE.png` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-beta)) which returns

   - `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` : Public download link but expires after 1 hour.
   - `webUrl` : Private download link, requires authentication.

.

2. `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/root:/PATH/TO/FILE.png:/createLink` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-beta)) with JSON body

```
{
    "type": "view",
    "scope": "anonymous"
}
```

which returns

- `link.webUrl` : Public link but is not a download link. It instead opens the file in OneDrive file viewer (which I then can't use/embed in HTML).

.

3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37951378/2219407

   Using previous `link.webUrl` to generate a download url ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online#encoding-sharing-urls)):

```
$linkWebUrl = "https://domain-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/username_domain/RANDOMTOKEN";
$b64 = base64_encode($linkWebUrl);
$b64 = trim($b64, "=");
$b64 = str_replace("/", "_", $b64);
$b64 = str_replace("+", "-", $b64);

$url = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!" . $b64 . "/root/content";
```

but it returns

`{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Invalid shares key."}}`

I think this is because I am mixing the Graph and OneDrive APIs so it doesn't recognize the key? Replacing `api.onedrive.com` with `graph.microsoft.com` doesn't work either as Graph requires the usual Authorization header.

Anyone know anything that works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You was very close but instead of step 3, `download=1` url query parameter needs to be appended to generated sharing link to create *a download link*, for example:

```
https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/{account-name}_onmicrosoft_com/{token}?download=1
```

That's it.

> Just a side note regarding the the error which occurs in step 3.
>
> A sharing link generated for OneDrive for Business or SharePoint
>   (https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com) could not be utilized via  OneDrive
>   Personal (https://api.onedrive.com) `shares` endpoint

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Can't believe it was something so small :) Is this officially documented somewhere for future reference?

Comment: Good to know! Regarding documentation, also not aware is it documented officially or not, this is the way how it was implemented in one of our projects