# How to transform a OneDrive download link to a direct link that does not prompt the user?

Tags: c#, download, onedrive

In my app, users can enter a URL pointing to a file to be downloaded. They might enter a OneDrive URL such as https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqyU3_Or8s5Bm3eKXA31Xg7DFYpm?e=p0vACS. A OneDrive URL like this is fine when downloading via a web browser. You get a page with a download button saying "Hmm... looks like this file doesn't have a preview" -- which it doesn't in many cases, and you just click on the button.

The problem comes in my app, when I attempt to download the URL in the normal way, because the page with the download button is interposed.

I've been looking high and low for a way to transform a URL of this form to one which can be downloaded directly, without an interposing page (such as can be done for Google Drive).

What would that transformation be? Adding "?download=1" is mentioned in some places, but does not work for me.

Comment: This isn't really a C# question, the URL can equally be used from anywhere. It's probably not even a great fit for [so], probably best posted on [su]

Comment: @Charlieface OK. It's interesting though that the url works in web browser, curl and Fiddler but not in my C# code.

Comment: Please ignore may last comment. It was for a different question.

Comment: For full solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76496242/how-to-directly-download-files-including-from-google-drive-onedrive-and-dropbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951114/direct-download-link-to-onedrive-file):

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!XXXXX/root/content
```

where XXXXX is the base 64 equivalent of the url.

In C#:

```
if ( url.StartsWith ( "https://1drv.ms/" ) )
{
    url = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!" + url.ToBase64 () + "/root/content";
}
```

This works for OneDrive personal. I don't think it would work for OneDrive business or Sharepoint - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#encoding-sharing-urls)

It would be great if someone could post solutions for those here, if they exist.

Comment: When I apply this method I get an error saying "The caller is not authenticated".

Comment: @Naitzirch Is your URL of the form https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqyU3_Or8s5Bm3eKXA31Xg7DFYpm?e=p0vACS ?

Comment: Not exactly, this is my link: https://1drv.ms/x/c/592951b5e0f544a7/EadE9eC1USkggFmOCgAAAAAB4_jqZzrpD9T6AhTDFHA2Rg

Comment: It appears Microsoft has changed the format of their One Drive link. I do not have a solution for that at the moment.