# How to create a permanent download link to a OneDrive file

Tags: excel, onedrive

I want to create a permanent download link for an .xlsx file in OneDrive.
First, I tried to create an embed and replace `edit` by `download`. Usually these links are of the form:

`https://onedrive.live.com/edit?resid=441509D410716450%211231&authkey=!AK6J7i3GDd5Zbc8&em=2`

However, the link to this file in the embed field was of the following form:

`https://1drv.ms/x/c/592951b5e0f544a7/EadE9eC1USkggFmOCgAAAAAB4_jqZzrpD9T6AhTDFHA2Rg`

So I tried expanding it with a link unshortener. This gave me a link that looked more like the first one. I applied the trick, but it gave me a page saying the file didn't exist or was unavailable. I noticed the link was missing the `authkey` part at the end though.

The second thing I tried was appending `?download=1` or `&download=1` at the end of the link (or the end of what the link expands to), but this resulted in nothing except the page loading the file like normal.

I also found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464263/how-to-transform-a-onedrive-download-link-to-a-direct-link-that-does-not-prompt) saying you could create a permanent download link by converting the shortened share link to Base64. Using this method, I got a page displaying the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "The caller is not authenticated."
  }
}
```

The expanded share link also didn't include the `authkey` part.

How do I create a link that I can turn into a permanent download link? Or how do I create a permanent download link for this file? I don't have access to the MS Graph API since I don't own a work or school account.

Comment: did you try something like [this](https://medium.com/@cldrivemanager01/how-to-get-direct-or-permanent-links-for-onedrive-files-d30d5b9b4382)?

Comment: I've tried this resource at @Matthias but to no avail unfortunately

Comment: how doesn't it work though? like what happens? which step does it error/not work?