# Direct download link to OneDrive file on v2.0?

Tags: url, download, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a link similar to this: https://1drv.ms/u/c/70d0917a4fce1e1f/EYn_RtUidqVIinvfQMU8zUsBTXuKGhQtdxWDnD1fqG7kGg.

How can I obtain the direct download link version of this?

I came across a solution mentioned in this [direct-download-link-to-onedrive-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951114/direct-download-link-to-onedrive-file) post, but it appears to only work for v1.0.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I also found this website but it also only works with v1.0
[onedrive-downloader](https://combokit.net/onedrive-downloader)